# how to properly use hardsurface alphas?

Tags: texture-painting, sculpting

i can barely find any tutorials or guides on how to do this exactly. how can i apply an alpha with enough **detail** without having to subdivide my mesh to hell. i cant seem to get enough detail from the alpha to go onto the mesh. would appreciate a step by step guide on the whole process but my main issue is that i cant get enough detail without having to subdivide the mesh a million times. dyntopo doesnt seem to help unless ive missed a setting or something.

**Any help much appreciated :)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd actually look at using Decal Machine add-on for this kind of thing - hard surface plugs that are baked into the texture I think is how it works. A paid add-on, but with all that automated work done for you it seems worth the investment.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45_mvLG-0x8